# Plugin para pesquisa personalizada com wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugin, algoritmo-de-busca

Existe algum plugin que facilita criar uma busca personalizada no seguimento imobiliário para Wordpress?

Modelo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Woocommerce????

Comment: não vai ser venda online, apenas a descrição do imóvel e foto.

Answer (score 1):

Esse pode dar certo, com  algumas modificações. O que você procura é um `Search com filter`:

[Ver Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-wp-query-search-filter/screenshots/)

Comment: Isso @Lollipop ! Obrigadão, vou testa-lo!

Comment: Testa e poe como resolvido se der certo.